# MySQL: Enumerate and count

Tags: mysql, count, enumerate

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`.

Example of the `table1` table.

```
^ invoice ^ valid ^ 
| 10       | yes   | 
| 11       | yes   | 
| 12       | no    |
```

Example of the `table2` table

```
^ invoice ^ detail ^ 
| 10       | A      | 
| 10       | C      | 
| 10       | F      | 
| 11       | A      | 
| 11       | F      |
| 10       | E      | 
| 12       | A      |
```

Want to select from table 2 all rows that:

- Have a valid invoice in table 1

And enumerate:

- the detail for each invoice
- the invoice

Here the desired result

```
^ invoice ^ detail ^ ordination ^ ordinationb      ^ 
| 10       | A      |     1       |       1         | 
| 10       | C      |     2       |       1         |  
| 10       | F      |     3       |       1         |  
| 11       | A      |     1       |       2         |  
| 11       | F      |     2       |       2         | 
| 10       | E      |     4       |       1         |
```

The sentence should valid for use in phpMyAdmin 4.8.4

Comment: Don't dramatically change your question after others have already answered.

Comment: I'm sorry for edit my question. previously other user misinterpreted the question. Now it's clear what I want to do. My apologizes. Also thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the MySQL 8+ way of doing this:

```
SELECT
    t2.Invoice,
    t2.`lines`,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Invoice ORDER BY t2.`lines`) line_order,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t2.Invoice) ordination
FROM table2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.Invoice = t2.Invoice AND t1.valid = 'yes');
```

[image]

### Demo

If you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 8, then you might have to resort to using session variables.  This can lead to an ugly query.  If you have a long term need for queries like this one, then I recommending upgrading to MySQL 8+.

**Edit:**

It just dawned on me that we can use correlated subqueries to simulate both your `ROW_NUMBER` and `DENSE_RANK` requirements.  Here is one way to do this query in MySQL 5.7 or earlier:

```
SELECT
    t2.Invoice,
    t2.detail,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 t
    WHERE t.Invoice = t2.Invoice AND t.detail <= t2.detail) ordination,
    t.dr AS ordinationb
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        t2.Invoice,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Invoice FROM table2) t
         WHERE t.Invoice <= t2.Invoice) dr
    FROM table2 t2
) t
    ON t.Invoice = t2.Invoice
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.Invoice = t2.Invoice AND t1.valid = 'yes')
ORDER BY
    t2.Invoice,
    t2.detail;
```

### Demo

Comment: @Josías `invoice number` is the same as `Invoice`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I just edited my example to clarify it and also reemplacing "lines" by "detail". you missed the result "ordinationb" 
On the other hand, I need a valid sentence for phpMyAdmin. your example for MySQL 8+ is not working in my case.

Comment: No, I have included the `ordination` column.  You shouldn't change your question after others have invested time to answer it.  And my answer is that you should upgrade to MySQL 8.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I'm sorry for editing. I thought it was the best. Thank you very much for your help. your solution for MySQL8 seems to be the best, but unfortunately, I can't use it and also can't upgrade MySQL. your previous example worked, just missed the latest column. Please, could you post again this code including the missed colum?

I'm sorry. I'm novice as programmer and also in stackoverflow. Thank you for your patience, and again my apologizes for the inconvenient.

Comment: @Josías Sorry for the delay, and I have given you a query which should run on your version of MySQL, and which seems to be working.  Hopefully you can see why you'd rather be using MySQL 8+, which supports analytic functions.  You _can_ do what you want usually, but it takes a lot more code.